Has Code Builder Been Corrupted?
Just tried to use Code Builder today and it has either been corrupted or some update has completely changed it - menu items are gone and replaced by weird commands like "&Enable Extension and {0}" - anyone seen this before?
I seemingly cannot close or open new projects to just start over.
Where normally I would see normal commands like "Find in Files" and such, I now see this:

